# Copying a function from hooked dll into process memory

Tags: c++, push

I hooked a dll, and got the handle of the process. I want to create a function in the dll, and execute it some times. (I know how to jump there, my problem is the copying)
Let's say my function looks like:

```
void Test()
{
     PUSH EAX;
     POP EAX;
}
```

I want to copy this, to the end of the target process (there are no instructions, just 00 everywhere), let's say the address is 0x12345

so when I debug the program, I'd like to see

```
    00012345    PUSH EAX
    00012346    POP EAX
```

I tried to use memcpy, but it didnt seem to work.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: that's a task for the linker, also you probably can't choose where to place and load a function in memory, it's a security feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to convince the hooked process to load another DLL, or convince it to call `VirtualAlloc` with write + execute permission bits, and then have your new code in the DLL or copy it into the allocated memory - bear in mind that you will need to relocate it in the allocated memory, it tends to be easier to just inject another DLL into the process. There are certainly quite a few "cheats" that do this already.